# Letter replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, character-replacement

I want to make letters like 'å ä ö' visible. I need to replace these letters with ascii code, I guess.

I have tried jquery and javascript, but it did not work. Look at the following code please:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>


    jQuery("#body").html(
    jQuery("#body").html().replace('ä', '&aring;')
);


     document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/ä/g, '&aring;');



    </script>



  </head>

  <body id="body">

    <div class="blog-masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="blog-nav">
          <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="index.php">Inlägg</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where exactly are the letters not displaying correctly? Following jsfiddle example shows that it should not be an issue to display these letters:
https://jsfiddle.net/yceaeqyj/

Comment: I want the js code to apply on  everything between <boddy> </body> tags. And I want to repleace all of  ' ä ' letters  to ' &aring;'. Is there a better way for doing this? Is my js code wrong?

Comment: I am not sure about your js code but @Déric Dallaire answers seems good on that area. However I think you should tell us why you are trying to change the letters like that, because maybe the issue can be avoided in a better way.

Comment: It is true. It works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using one of the three methods below.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/XKGdAq)

**JQuery**

```
// using a regex on the first parameter of replace, 
// picks all the 'ä' instead of the first one 
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/ä/g,'&aring;'); 
$("body").html(replaced);
```

**JavaScript**

```
// using a regex on the first parameter of replace, 
// picks all the 'ä' instead of the first one 
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/ä/g, '&aring;');
```

**Better Solution**

A better alternative to the two previous code sample is to convert your file to the right encoding. In order to do that, make sure you this snippet in the `head` of you HTML document.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If that's not working, you also have to make sure the file is saved with encoding UTF-8. If you're using Notepad++, this is done via `Encoding > Encode in UTF-8`.